# Cannot resolve symbol getJSONObject with import org.json

Tags: java, json, spring, maven

The Following Code is my RestClient:
I'm not sure what is going on as I have the maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.json</groupId>
  <artifactId>json</artifactId>
  <version>20180130</version>
</dependency>
```

And I have imported in my RestClient:

```
import org.json.*;
```

But when I type in my RestClient:

```
public void put(final String json) {
    JSONObject jsonWh = json.getJSONObject("json");
}
```

I keep getting the following error (when I mouse over 'getJSONObject'):

> Cannot resolve symbol getJSONObject(java.lang.String)

'json' when printed looks like:

```
{"json":"{"name":"test", "contact":{"mobile":"088","home":"089"}, "type":"family"}"}
```

The variable json is passed in from my front-end react web app which passes json to the endpoint /createcontact.
In my java controller:

```
@PostMapping(value="/createcontact")
public ResponseEntity<String> createContact(@RequestBody final String json) {
    restClient.put("/contacts/createcontact", json);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(httpStatus.CREATED);
}
```

Can someone please help me figure this out? Perhaps I have the wrong import? I thought this should be the correct maven dependency because of [this page](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?class=org.json.JSONObject&method=getJSONObject)
but I'm not sure.

I am basically trying to get all of the information after "json".

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Show the rest of the code. Notably, how did you build variable 'json'?

Comment: I updated my question, I hope I've made it more clear. json is being built in my react front end web app and is being passed into my java backend through another endpoint.

Comment: ... Dude. Where is `JSONObject jsonWh = json.getJSONObject("json");`? Come on -\_-°

Comment: are you sure you are using the right import and lib?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding dependencies to your project will not add new methods to the existing classes available. Notably, adding dependency `org.json` will not add the method getJSONObject() to the class String. Nothing will add new methods to existing classes.

By adding this dependency, you get access to new classes, notably class JSONObject.

So you could do:

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(json);
JSONObject jsonWh = obj.getJSONObject("json");
```

However, don't do that. You're using a REST webservice framework. It will handle for you deserializing JSON requests into Java objects, without the need to find additional dependencies by yourself.

Just read tutorials about how your framework best does that for you.